# Inserting HTML is a Shopify page renders as text

Tags: html, shopify

I built this very basic html page page http://setch.me/popcorn/ to insert it in a shopify page
and this was the result https://roguepopcorn.com/pages/do-you-know-whats-in-your-popcorn
just the code rendered as text.

how to insert it properly?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert HTML into your page in Shopify, you need to switch to Source View and then paste your HTML code
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to insert html into your page.

One is in the html editor of the page
second is by creating page template and add html in that page template

For the first, you have to click on "<>" option on the content section to enable the html editor.

Thanks